# Filter by file extension in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

I have some information stored in MySQL and I want to fetch certain data. I have a column that contains "File_names" and these names correspond with all kinds of files like images, scripts, txts...[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI0fZ.png). There's a lot of script names of different programming languages like cpp, PHP, sh, py,...

I only need the script related data. In my head is clear: fetch data only if the file name corresponds with a script (we know this because of its extension). But I don't know how to translate this idea to a MySQL query. I'm also thinking about fetching all info from MySQL and then filter it using python but I still have no idea.

I have a python solution in my mind but I think it's too complex. For example, if I create a list with a lot of script extensions, fetch all info from MySQL, split all file_names obtaining the extension, and finally compare it with the script extensions list. I think there's an easier/efficient way to do this.

Any idea?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Could you add a describe from your table? A simple `describe your_table;`. I answered your question with a generic query. If you provide the details of the table, I can make it more conclusive for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple query:

```sql
SELECT File_names
FROM Your_table
WHERE (File_names like '%.php'
OR File_names like '%.cpp'
OR File_names like '%.sh')
```

Add more `OR` options according to your needs.